What is the allowed time for offering Jumu’ah prayers?
Assalamu Alaykum, I have Jummah prayer in my school alhamdulillah but Dhuhr is at 1pm right now and we do the prayer during lunch at 12:00-12:45 pm. The prayer plus the khutbah takes 30 minutes. If we were to do the Jummah at its proper time, we would miss almost half of the lesson (for reference, a period is 75 minutes). My school had already asked a local Sheikh and he said it would be permissible to pray earlier. My friends are concerned about the source. Would it be permissible to pray Jummah earlier due to our circumstance?

Jumu’ah prayer has a starting time and an ending time. It can be performed within this window without any blame. It is invalid to perform it outside this window.
The time for Jumu’ah ends at the start of the time for Asr, it can not be offered as Qada after this time.
The starting time for Jumu’ah is disagreed upon:
According to the majority opinion, it is the same as the time for Zuhr, i.e. after zawaal (when the sun has passed the meridian).

أن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم كان يصلي الجمعة حين تميل الشمس‏‏
The Prophet ﵌ would pray the Friday prayer when the sun was declining
—  Bukhari , Jami at-Tirmidhi

A minority view (that of the Hanbalis) is that the starting time for Jumu’ah is the same as that for Eid prayers, and hence it can be offered before midday.
The answer to your specific question depends on your location.
You need to find the starting time for Zuhr. This time varies with the location on the earth and with the time of the year. Use a prayer time app to help you, the time may be different from the time at which Zuhr is offered in your local mosque. As long as you perform Jumu’ah after the starting time of Zuhr and before the time for Asr it would be valid. Performing it before this time is disagreed upon. Both the sermon and prayer must be within the allowed time window.
Ref: Fiqh al-Islami wa Adillatuhu
